# Symfony application can never load config.php

Tags: php, symfony

I am a beginner with Symfony framework, I have gone through the [Symfony Quick tour](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html), and then I tried to run a Symfony app [Codebender](https://github.com/codebendercc/codebender.cc) from github. The installation seems to be ok. I have all the required modules installed.

My problem is when I try to access `http://localhost/Symfony/web/config.php`, the page never loads, i.e., the page loading action never terminates.

I have nothing in the error logs and the access logs show `200 OK` message.

```
::1 - - [13/May/2013:14:09:30 +0200] "GET /Symfony/web/config.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2379 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0"
```

The same is the case when I try to access other urls like `app_dev.php`

Comment: Try by changing permission of your project

Answer (score 0):

Using Symfony is not like simple php.
You have to enter an urls starting with localhost/your_application/web/app_dev.php/
then the route that you want to access .
You should take a look at rooting in symfony